# matrix addition program. If i type one newline character it is skipping one line .and gets on the third line

Tags: c

I am writing a matrix addition program. The expected output should each row on a single line.But after the first row  output if i use a new line character it is skipping one line and printing on the second line the second row.Its as if i have given two new line characters.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int x,y,z,w,i,j;
    int a[3][3],b[3][3],c[3][3];

    scanf("%d",&x);
    scanf("%d",&y);

    //getchar();
    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            scanf(" %d",&a[i][j]);
    scanf("%d",&z);
    //getchar();
    scanf("%d",&w);
    //getchar();
    for(i=0;i<z;i++)
        for(j=0;j<w;j++)
            scanf(" %d",&b[i][j]);

    for(i=0;i<z;i++)
        for(j=0;j<w;j++)
            c[i][j]=a[i][j]+b[i][j];

    for(i=0;i<x;i++){
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
            printf("%d ",c[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pArvs.png)

Comment: Please, format your code. It is difficult to read. Thanks.

Comment: A user3068424 said. Add some comments and some proper var names.

Comment: Program works perfectly here, one line per row. Input prompts would go a long way to remind the user what input to give. I had to guess, from looking at the program. Please also check the validity of the inputs before using them to index arrays.

Comment: I really don't see any problem in format of output -https://ideone.com/jTsPS2

Comment: I do not understand the question. It is contradictory. You want each row on a separate line, but you are puzzled why each row is on a new line. Show what you input, and the exact output. (By editing the question).

Comment: Please check out the output link below the program where i have added the screen shot of my output and the expected output.Check the gap between rows.In my output the gap is more as if it is taking one extra line.I am solving program on one website.The matrix addition output is correct.but because of the more gap between the rows.The my output is not matching with expected output –

Answer (score 0):

You have a significant number of instances where undefined behavior can occur in your code. The number one place you can prevent against attempted access of an uninitialized value is to *initialize all your variables*, especially your two-dimensional arrays. That will prevent inadvertent iteration over any uninitialized values within your array, e.g.

```
    int x,y,z,w,i,j;
    int a[3][3] = {{0}}, b[3][3] = {{0}}, c[3][3] = {{0}};
    x = y = z = w = 0;
```

Next, when taking user input, always, *always* validate user input. That means at minimum validating the return of `scanf` to insure the expected number of conversions have successfully taken place, e.g. for your `x`, `y` array:

```
    /* x & y input and validation */
    if (scanf (" %d", &x) != 1 || x < 0 || x > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for x '%d'.\n", x);
        return 1;
    }
    if (scanf (" %d", &y) != 1 || y < 0 || y > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for y '%d'.\n", y);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)     /* fill a -- validate input */
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            if (scanf(" %d",&a[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input a[%d][%d].\n",
                        i, j);
                return 1;
            }
```

You also need to validate the dimensions of the arrays `a` and `b` match before adding all indexes between the arrays (some of which would be empty and uninitialized without initializations of the arrays), e.g.

```
    if (x != z || w != y)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: dimension mismatch - limiting addition.\n");
```

Before adding the arrays, you must limit the indexes to just those with values. (it is up to you whether you display the complete array after addition). One way is simply to limit the addition to the minimum index for each dimension between array `a` and `b`, e.g. (a *ternary* operator is used below to set the minimum value)

```
     /* add a + b -- validating max dimensions to prevent overrun */
    int xdim = z > x ? x : z;
    int ydim = w > y ? y : w;
    for (i = 0; i < xdim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ydim; j++)
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
```

Finally, opening your code with spacing may help make some of the subtle points more apparent and readable. (that is entirely up to you -- the older you get, the greater you will appreciate the additional spacing...) Putting all the pieces together, you could do something like the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (void) {

    int x,y,z,w,i,j;
    int a[3][3] = {{0}}, b[3][3] = {{0}}, c[3][3] = {{0}};
    x = y = z = w = 0;

    /* x & y input and validation */
    if (scanf (" %d", &x) != 1 || x < 0 || x > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for x '%d'.\n", x);
        return 1;
    }
    if (scanf (" %d", &y) != 1 || y < 0 || y > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for y '%d'.\n", y);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < x; i++)     /* fill a -- validate input */
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            if (scanf(" %d",&a[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input a[%d][%d].\n",
                        i, j);
                return 1;
            }

    /* z & w input and validation */
    if (scanf (" %d", &z) != 1 || z < 0 || z > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for z '%d'.\n", z);
        return 1;
    }
    if (scanf (" %d", &w) != 1 || w < 0 || w > 3) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input for w '%d'.\n", w);
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < z; i++)     /* fill b -- validate input */
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++)
            if (scanf(" %d",&b[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid input b[%d][%d].\n",
                        i, j);
                return 1;
            }

    if (x != z || w != y)
        fprintf (stderr, "warning: dimension mismatch - limiting addition.\n");

    printf ("\n array a[%d][%d]\n\n", x, y);
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf (" %3d", a[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    printf ("\n array b[%d][%d]\n\n", z, w);
    for (i = 0; i < z; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < w; j++)
            printf (" %3d", b[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    /* add a + b -- validating max dimensions to prevent overrun */
    int xdim = z > x ? x : z;
    int ydim = w > y ? y : w;
    for (i = 0; i < xdim; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < ydim; j++)
            c[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];

    printf ("\n array c[%d][%d]\n\n", xdim, ydim);
    for (i = 0; i < xdim; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < ydim; j++)
            printf (" %3d", c[i][j]);
        putchar ('\n');
    }
    putchar ('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** `main()` is a function of type `int` and therefore returns a value)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/arradd.txt
3
3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
3
3
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/arrayadd <dat/arradd.txt

 array a[3][3]

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

 array b[3][3]

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

 array c[3][3]

   2   4   6
   8  10  12
  14  16  18
```

Look things over and let me know if you have any additional questions.

Comment: Please check out the output link below the program where i have added the screen shot of my output and the expected output.Check the gap between rows.In my output the gap is more as if it is taking one extra line.I am solving program on one website.The matrix addition output is correct.but because of the more gap between the rows.The my output is not matching with expected output

Comment: In the link you show an additional `'\n'`, but that isn't shown in the code you show in the question. Please add the print routine that produced the output below the link you posted, otherwise all I can do is guess. Also what OS? Linux or windoze or other?